# Falta revisar en Transifex $tag0$ y $tag1$ y similares

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

En las páginas de sinónimos de etiquetas aparece `etiqueta and etiqueta`. Ejemplo:

[image]

Recién traduje las cadenas que incluyen $tag0$ que aparentemente abarca los casos en los que una etiqueta tiene como sinónimo de 2 a 9 etiquetas. Falta hacer la revisión.

Enlace a búsqueda en transifex

[$tag0$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/136222153?q=%24tag0%24)

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Y antes de que publicara esto ya había quedado [revisado e importado, pero ocurrió un error.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43407635#43407635). Por lo pronto gracias **g3rv4**.

Answer (score 2):

Veo que esto ya se solucionó:

En la página de sinónimos de la etiqueta [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) (sin tilde, por cierto), es decir, en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-hoja-de-calculo/synonyms vemos:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]